# query_post and have_posts issue

Tags: php, wordpress

I have 20 posts and i need to display text after every 5 posts. So i have asked the query in stackoverflow and i have get the solution. I have tried the query in my site. My code is,

```
<?php
query_posts( array(orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php ($p%5 == 0) ? ($p/5): ""; ?>
<?php if($p==5):
echo hai;
elseif($p==10):
echo fine;
endif;
?>
<?php
$p++;
?>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
```

It works fine when echoeing "Hai" and "Fine" after 5 posts.

BUt while replacing the code in the below format. The posts are not fetching correctly. Please anyone help me. I need to add my own category id 3 after 5th post and category id 4 after 10th post

```
<?php
query_posts( array(orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php ($p%5 == 0) ? ($p/5): ""; ?>
<?php if($p==5):
    if (have_posts()) :
    query_posts( array(cat=>3, orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php endif; 
elseif($p==10):
echo fine;
endif;
?>
<?php
$p++;
?>
<?php
endwhile; 
?>
```

inplace of `echo fine;` i need to add the same code used above in place of `echo hai;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_reset_query()`.

wp_reset_query() restores the $wp_query.

```
<?php
query_posts( array(orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
$p = 1;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>
<div class="post">
<?php the_title(); ?>
<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
</div>
<?php ($p%5 == 0) ? ($p/5): ""; ?>
<?php if($p==5):
    if (have_posts()) :
    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts( array(cat=>3, orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title();
       ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php endif; 
elseif($p==10):
     wp_reset_query(); 
    if (have_posts()) :
    wp_reset_query();
    query_posts( array(cat=>3, orderby=>post_date, order=>desc) );
    while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <?php the_title(); ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?> 
    <?php endif; 
endif;
$p++
?>

<?php
endwhile; 
?>
```

Comment: After 5th post the category id 3 is working fine. But after 10th post category id 4 is not working. And also 6th post is missing..@404 error